# Pasta “.m2” para o arquivo settings.xml no Windows Server 2008?

Tags: java, maven

Tenho uma aplicação Java EE com servidor Wildfly-10.1.0.Final que usa esta pasta para adicionar o arquivo `settings.xml` , mas dentro do Windows server 2008 eu não tenho está pasta no usuário, como eu poderia fazer a criação desta pasta? Agradeço a ajuda.

Comment: Não entendi. Você quer usar o WinServer para desenvolvimento ou para deploy?

Comment: Está pasta padrão não existia, mais após eu ter configurado o mavem ela passou a existir

Comment: Você está usando essa máquina para desenvolvimento? A pasta .m2 é só para desenvolvimento.

Comment: Correto, eu já tenho a solução